# J2k to ISO conversion in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I had a requirement like i need to convert images from J2k format to ISO format.As far as i googled we cant do this directly in java,We have first convert j2k to RAW format and the corresponding RAW format to ISO format.

Anyone please suggest me Can we this entire thing in java or we need some c++ libraries along with java.

I Surfed ion internet and found like there is something like JAVA-
CARD API but seems like commercial product.

Can anyone help me with your valuable ideas or suggestions in this process.

Thanks in advance,
Raghavan...

Answer (score -1):

The JAI contains plugins for reading and writing JPEG2000 and JPEG (ISO-10918-1/ITU-T.81 and ISO-14495-1/ITU-T.87) in the com.sun.media.jai packages.
See [jai docs](https://jai-imageio.dev.java.net/).

The javacard api seems to be something totally unrelated to image processing to me.

HTH